# Will the form submission in my HTML code still submit the data in the form fields if my input elements were nested in a way achieve desired styling?

Tags: html, forms

I am writing some form markup just to practicing html.

However, I am not sure if nesting the form input field two levels down from the parent form tag will still be a valid html markup in order to get my data submitted to the server.

I am doing this to achieve a desired styling which I did. So the question I have is whether or not the server will receive all data from each form field. Please note I wish to submit the form via the `<input type="submit">` button which I have not included in the code below. Just want to make sure the code is valid before I do so.

Here's the code.
`

```
<form>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            id="name"
            placeholder="Your name"
            required
        />
    </div>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            id="email"
            placeholder="you@company.com"
            required
        />
    </div>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="tel">Phone number</label>
        <div id="contact-number-container">
            <label for="country-select"></label>
            <select name="country-select" id="country-select">
                <option value="US">US</option>
                <option value="AU">AU</option>
                <option value="SG">SG</option>
                <option value="MY">MY</option>
                <option value="IN">IN</option>
                <option value="CN">CN</option>
            </select>
            <input
                type="tel"
                name="tel"
                id="tel"
                placeholder="+1 (555) 000-0000"
                required
            />
        </div>
    </div>
    <label for="story">How can we help?</label>
    <textarea
        id="story"
        name="story"
        rows="5"
        cols="33"
        placeholder="Tell us a little about the project..."
    ></textarea>
</form>;
```

`

I am trying to have a selector to appear beside an input field of type "tel" that sits side by side horizontally and I wrapped them inside a container div with id `contact-number-container`.
The label for the input field of type "tel" is actually outside the container div. I wonder if this arrangement is ok for form submission to be successful. (i.e. submitting the data via a `<input type="submit">`)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the form actually does submit all the form fields as required despite the nesting of input elements further down from the parent (form tag).

This is what happen when I tried to submit the form via a
Submit form button.

1. The page is refreshed
2. In the Network tab of the chrome browser, I see that the url that I have posted to (localhost in my case) has the form data shown in the payload tab.

Hence, it seems like it might not really how you structure your html within the form tags, the urllenencoded data still seems to have everything from my form fields.

[image]